# I Render a list of Movies via an API and I created a modal to display onClick each movie details !Help, REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, render, each

I'm mapping my list but I want to render only the element details that I click on in the modal and I can't reach it. I know there is something to do with the id

Can somebody help me ?

[my modal map()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymo3f.png)
[parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpaZg.png)

Comment: Hi, I'm supposing that you are changing the flag modalDisplay when a row is clicked and you want to show the detail of the selected one, if so, you must pass only the record you want to display (set the selected one with useState if there are no other state management in use) to the ModalItem not all your records.

Comment: Thanks ! I find a solution